# IntelliJ IDEA - Not compiling

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, compilation

Using InteliJ IDEA, version 2017.2.5,

from some undetermined point in the past, it is not auto-compiling my code on the go.

This implies many things:

- Not coloring certain classes, variables or attributes.
- Not analything nor compiling code.

This means that I just get compile errors from maven when I run my package or similar goals.

I've been checking some of the settings, but I don't find anything. Any clue about this misconfigure thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible you have switched the editor into *Power Save Mode*. You can turn off Power Save Mode by invoking the `File | Power Save Mode` menu item. Or use `Help | Find Action...` (<kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>),type the first letters of "power save mode" and press Enter.

Comment: It definitely was that. I'm new with IntelliJ IDEA. Thank you!